# Syntax Error with JS links via assets in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, zurb-foundation

Trying to load up foundation in Laravel but I keep getting a syntax error.

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>"></script>\r' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'"
```

My JS links are as follow:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/vendor/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/vendor/what-input.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/vendor/foundation.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/pickadate/lib/picker.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js') }}"></script>
```

Running the artisan serve and test the file via the browser I can see it is directed correctly but the syntax error seem to be an issue as jquery isnt working at all.

Not being an expert with Laravel (started recently), and having spent many hours trying to find the issue, I am at a loss as to what the issue is.

A screenshot of the browser showing the error message is as follow:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try removing or putting '/' before the asset parameter.

Comment: thanks, it seems the issue was my laravel install... reinstalled it and it is now working. thanks a lot for the help though.